# Adding Border Around Bootstrap Tabs

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the Bootstrap tab markup as seen below:

```css
.nav-tabs {

    &.nav-tabs-alt {
        padding-top: 30px;

        li {
            a {
                color: @brand-info;
                font-size: 16px;
            }
        }

        li.active {

            a {
                background-color: #fff;
                color: @brand-primary !important;
                font-size: 16px;
            }
        }
    }
}

.tab-content {
    &.tab-content-alt {

    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Title Page</title>
  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
    <div>

        <!-- Nav tabs -->
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-tabs-alt" role="tablist">
            <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#call" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Call Us</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#email" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Email Us</a></li>
        </ul>

        <!-- Tab panes -->
        <div class="tab-content tab-content-alt">
            <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in active" id="call">...</div>
            <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="email">...</div>
        </div>

    </div>

  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
  <!-- Bootstrap JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

However, I'd like it if a border enclosed the entire tab as seen below, but in my example, the border isn't fluid and there is a break in it. Any ideas how to achieve this result?

```css
.nav-tabs {

    &.nav-tabs-alt {
        padding-top: 30px;

        li {
            a {
                color: @brand-info;
                font-size: 16px;
            }
        }

        li.active {

            a {
                background-color: #fff;
                color: @brand-primary !important;
                font-size: 16px;
            }
        }
    }
}

.tab-content.tab-content-alt {
        border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
        border-left: 1px solid #ddd;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
        border-top-color:transparent;
        border-radius: 4px;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Title Page</title>
  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
    <div>

                    <!-- Nav tabs -->
                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-tabs-alt" role="tablist">
                        <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#call" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Call Us</a></li>
                        <li role="presentation"><a href="#email" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Email Us</a></li>
                    </ul>

                    <!-- Tab panes -->
                    <div class="tab-content tab-content-alt">
                        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in active" id="call">...</div>
                        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="email">...</div>
                    </div>

                </div>

  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
  <!-- Bootstrap JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not sure if i got the idea, i just changed the border-radius to zero, and this creates the efect of fluid container

```css
.nav-tabs {

    &.nav-tabs-alt {
        padding-top: 30px;

        li {
            a {
                color: @brand-info;
                font-size: 16px;
            }
        }

        li.active {

            a {
                background-color: #fff;
                color: @brand-primary !important;
                font-size: 16px;
            }
        }
    }
}

.tab-content.tab-content-alt {
        border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
        border-left: 1px solid #ddd;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
        border-top-color:transparent;
        border-radius: 0px;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Title Page</title>
  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
    <div>

                    <!-- Nav tabs -->
                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-tabs-alt" role="tablist">
                        <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#call" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Call Us</a></li>
                        <li role="presentation"><a href="#email" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Email Us</a></li>
                    </ul>

                    <!-- Tab panes -->
                    <div class="tab-content tab-content-alt">
                        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in active" id="call">...</div>
                        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="email">...</div>
                    </div>

                </div>

  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
  <!-- Bootstrap JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>

</html>
```